# Is it possible to define optional fields in a Smooks CSV reader

Tags: csv, field, option-type, smooks

I want to read CSV entries with a Smooks CSV reader.
But my problem is how to define a field as optional.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd">

  <csv:reader fields="field1,field2,OPTONAL_FIELD3,$ignore$+" />

</smooks-resource-list>
```

Is there any way to define such a configuration?

The data I want to read looks like this:

123,4,opt1

456,7

If field 3 is declared as normal in the configuration, the line must always ends with a ',' like this:

456,7,